# Search bar for JPanel text

Tags: java, search, jpanel

I have wrote a java program, it has a `CardLayout` with a `JPanel` for each card.

The `JPanel` contains long text, I just need to implement a little "search bar" that just search for specified text on the viewed `JPanel`.

It simply has to **highlight the searched text** inside the `JPanel`.

In order to make it clearer, I'm talking about something like the Chrome's of Firefox's search bar (ctrl-f) but that works just for one `JPanel` in my program.

Here is a picture.

[image]

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a small search `JPanel` that is positioned above your text `JPanel`. Both `JPanel`s would be inside of another `JPanel`. I'd use a `JTextField` and a `JButton`, because I like the user in control of when to search.

Here's one of my GUI's with a search `JPanel`.

[image: Cobol Paragraph Structure]

And here's the code to create the search `JPanel`.  Note that I used a `JPanel`.  You only extend Swing components when you want to override one of the component methods.

```
package gov.bop.cobol.paragraph.structure.view;

import gov.bop.cobol.paragraph.structure.model.ParagraphStructureModel;
import gov.bop.cobol.paragraph.structure.thread.SearchActionThread;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SearchPanel {

    protected JPanel                    panel;

    protected JTextField                findTextField;

    protected ParagraphStructureFrame   frame;

    protected ParagraphStructureModel   model;

    public SearchPanel(ParagraphStructureFrame frame,
            ParagraphStructureModel model) {
        this.frame = frame;
        this.model = model;
        createPartControl();
    }

    protected void createPartControl() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));

        JLabel findLabel = new JLabel("Search:");
        panel.add(findLabel);

        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(6, 0)));

        findTextField = new JTextField(30);
        panel.add(findTextField);

        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(6, 0)));

        JButton findButton = new JButton("Search");
        findButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                String s = findTextField.getText().toUpperCase().trim();
                if (!s.equals("")) {
                    findTextField.setText(s);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new SearchActionThread(frame,
                            model, s));
                    thread.start();
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(findButton);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

}
```